# Does Virtualbox machine folder or virtual hard disk location have to be on SSD for performance increase?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I was wondering if there are any issues with my setup being that the Virtualbox Machine folder is in its default location (C:\Users\Name\VirtualBox VMs)(SSD), and the actual virtual hard disk is located on a different drive (HDD). Are there any performance benefits of the Machine folder being on an SSD since the actual virtual drive is on an HDD?

Thanks!

Comment: You can get performance benefits by separating your large and/or often changed data files on to separate disks than where your system files are stored because these files can cause disk fragmentation, which can then cause other things such as thrashing, high CPU etc.  One example is storing your Paging File on a separate disk than where system files are stored can give you performance gains.  However if you have underlying issues or something else is the main reason for a bottleneck then this won't be guaranteed to resolve your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The virtual machine's folder only contains information such as CPU count, RAM, etc. The real read/write is being handled by your `VHD` or `VDD`file (based on your choice) which you will experience much more performance if you move it to an SSD drive.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I will just move the machine folder to the HDD and the virtual drive to SSD.

Comment: Glad it could help.